# Nokogiri, Omniauth and 1.9.2p290 => total failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, nokogiri, bundler

I am running: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Nokogiri is seg-faulting on me and I think the issue has been solved at:

https://github.com/ender672/nokogiri

However if I do:

```
gem 'nokogiri',  :git => 'git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git'
```

I get a successful bundle install, bundle pack, and even did a bundle update to generate a new Gemfile. However, I can't even get to console:

```
git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

rvm just updated my 1.9.2 to p290 and I think that might be causing the problem. Maybe I should just step back to the last stable build. I would be interested in how to do that, but I don't know the previous build number.

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'simplecov', '>= 0.4.0', :require => false, :group => :test
gem 'httparty'

gem "rails", "3.1.0.rc5"
# Rails 3.1 - Asset Pipeline

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'coffee-script'
  gem 'uglifier'  
  gem 'json'
  gem 'jquery-rails'  
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.0.0.beta.12'
end


# Bundle gems needed for Mongoid
gem "mongoid", "~>2.0.1"   #, "2.0.0.rc.7"
gem "bson_ext"  #, "1.1.5"

gem 'rake', '0.8.7'

# Bundle gem needed for Devise and cancan
gem "devise", "~>1.4.0" # ,"1.1.7"
gem "cancan"
#gem "omniauth", :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git' # maybe we need this latest version instead of the gem -tbb
#gem "govkit" #, :git => 'git://github.com/tbbooher/govkit.git'
#gem "nytimes-congress"
#gem "geokit"
#gem 'drumbone'
gem "googlecharts"
#gem "omniauth" "0.2.6"
#gem 'omniauth', '>= 0.2.6'
gem 'omniauth', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'

# we need some stuff too (tbb)
gem "formtastic"

# for installation
#gem "heroku"

# for deployment
gem "capistrano"

# and server
gem 'unicorn'

# time to connect to opencongress
gem 'json'
#gem 'ym4r'
gem 'geocoder'

#group :after_initialize do
gem 'nokogiri' #,  :git => 'git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git'# :git => 'git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git'
gem "feedzirra" #ls
#, :git => "git://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra.git"
#end
gem 'sax-machine'

# Bundle gem needed for paperclip and attachments
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"

# MongoID Extensions and extras
gem 'mongoid-tree', :require => 'mongoid/tree'

# Bundle gems for views
gem "haml"
gem "will_paginate"
gem 'escape_utils'
gem "RedCloth", "4.2.5"

# Markdown
# do "easy_install pygments" on your system
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'albino'
#gem "nokogiri", "1.4.6"

# maybe we need rack here

# Bundle gems for development 
group :development do
  gem "nifty-generators"
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'rdoc'
  gem "rails3-generators"
  gem "ruby-debug19"
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'yard' #broken in OS X 10.7 see how to workarround this issue 
end

# Bundle gems for testing
group :test do
  #gem 'webmock'
  #gem 'vcr'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'json_pure'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'rspec', '2.6.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc9'
  gem 'spork-testunit'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'ruby-growl'
  gem 'autotest-growl'
  gem "mocha"
  gem "fabrication"
  gem "gherkin"
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem "autotest-fsevent"
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git
  revision: 26fb41d840a9f50da1d3ab4c778ef5a20581808b
  specs:
    oa-basic (0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.0)
    oa-core (0.3.0.rc1)
    oa-enterprise (0.3.0.rc1)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
      net-ldap (~> 0.2.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      pyu-ruby-sasl (~> 0.0.3.1)
      rubyntlm (~> 0.1.1)
    oa-more (0.3.0.rc1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.0)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.0)
    oa-oauth (0.3.0.rc1)
      faraday (~> 0.7.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.2.2)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      oauth (~> 0.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 0.5.0)
    oa-openid (0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      rack-openid (~> 1.3.1)
      ruby-openid-apps-discovery (~> 1.2.0)
    omniauth (0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-basic (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-enterprise (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-more (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-oauth (= 0.3.0.rc1)
      oa-openid (= 0.3.0.rc1)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    RedCloth (4.2.5)
    ZenTest (4.6.0)
    actionmailer (3.1.0.rc5)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.0.rc5)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.1)
      rack-cache (~> 1.0.2)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0.beta.12)
    activemodel (3.1.0.rc5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.0.rc5)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      arel (~> 2.1.4)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.0.rc5)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0.rc5)
    activesupport (3.1.0.rc5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.6)
    albino (1.3.3)
      posix-spawn (>= 0.3.6)
    archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
    arel (2.1.4)
    autotest (4.4.6)
      ZenTest (>= 4.4.1)
    autotest-fsevent (0.2.5)
      sys-uname
    autotest-growl (0.2.9)
    autotest-rails (4.1.0)
      ZenTest
    bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
    bson (1.3.1)
    bson_ext (1.3.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.5)
    capistrano (2.8.0)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capybara (1.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 0.2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.2.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    cocaine (0.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
    columnize (0.3.4)
    crack (0.1.8)
    cucumber (1.0.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.4.5)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.5)
    cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
      capybara (>= 1.0.0)
      cucumber (~> 1.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.6)
    curb (0.7.15)
    database_cleaner (0.6.7)
    devise (1.4.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1.2)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.0.3)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    escape_utils (0.2.3)
    execjs (1.2.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fabrication (1.0.1)
    factory_girl (2.0.3)
    factory_girl_rails (1.1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (0.9.5)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    faraday (0.7.4)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1.0)
      rack (= 1.1.0)
    feedzirra (0.0.24)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.8)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      curb (>= 0.2.3)
      loofah (>= 0.3.1)
      nokogiri (> 0.0.0)
      sax-machine (>= 0.0.12)
    ffi (1.0.9)
    formtastic (1.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 2.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.7)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    geocoder (1.0.2)
    gherkin (2.4.5)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    googlecharts (1.6.7)
    haml (3.1.2)
    highline (1.6.2)
    hike (1.2.0)
    httparty (0.7.8)
      crack (= 0.1.8)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.12)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.5.3)
    json_pure (1.5.3)
    kgio (2.6.0)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    libv8 (3.3.10.2)
    linecache19 (0.5.12)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    loofah (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    mocha (0.9.12)
    mongo (1.3.1)
      bson (>= 1.3.1)
    mongoid (2.0.2)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
      mongo (~> 1.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
    mongoid-paperclip (0.0.5)
      paperclip (~> 2.3.6)
    mongoid-tree (0.6.1)
      mongoid (~> 2.0)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    multi_xml (0.2.2)
    multipart-post (1.1.3)
    net-ldap (0.2.2)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.1.4)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    nifty-generators (0.4.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    oauth (0.4.5)
    oauth2 (0.5.0)
      faraday (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    paperclip (2.3.16)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    polyglot (0.3.2)
    posix-spawn (0.3.6)
    pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.2)
    rack-cache (1.0.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.1)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-openid (1.3.1)
      rack (>= 1.1.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.0.rc5)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activerecord (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activeresource (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.0.rc5)
    rails-erd (0.4.5)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 0.9.18)
    rails3-generators (0.17.4)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.1.0.rc5)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0.rc5)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    raindrops (0.7.0)
    rake (0.8.7)
    rdoc (3.9.1)
    redcarpet (1.17.2)
    rest-client (1.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.6.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
    rspec-core (2.6.4)
    rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
    rspec-rails (2.6.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.6.0)
    ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      linecache19 (>= 0.5.11)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      linecache19 (>= 0.5.11)
      ruby-debug-base19 (>= 0.11.19)
    ruby-graphviz (0.9.21)
    ruby-growl (3.0)
    ruby-openid (2.1.8)
    ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.7)
    ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
      archive-tar-minitar (>= 0.5.2)
    rubyntlm (0.1.1)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.7)
    sass-rails (3.1.0.rc.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0.rc1)
      railties (~> 3.1.0.rc1)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (>= 2.0.0.beta.9)
    sax-machine (0.0.20)
      nokogiri (> 0.0.0)
    selenium-webdriver (0.2.2)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.9)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    simplecov (0.4.2)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.4.4)
    simplecov-html (0.4.5)
    spork (0.9.0.rc9)
    spork-testunit (0.0.5)
      spork (>= 0.6.0)
    sprockets (2.0.0.beta.13)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)
    sys-uname (0.8.5)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.6)
    test-unit (2.3.1)
    therubyracer (0.9.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.2)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.29)
    uglifier (1.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.0.1)
      kgio (~> 2.4)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.6)
    warden (1.0.5)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (2.3.15)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yard (0.7.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  RedCloth (= 4.2.5)
  ZenTest
  albino
  autotest
  autotest-fsevent
  autotest-growl
  autotest-rails
  bson_ext
  cancan
  capistrano
  capybara
  coffee-script
  cucumber
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  devise (~> 1.4.0)
  escape_utils
  execjs
  fabrication
  factory_girl
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  feedzirra
  formtastic
  geocoder
  gherkin
  googlecharts
  haml
  httparty
  jquery-rails
  json
  json_pure
  launchy
  mocha
  mongoid (~> 2.0.1)
  mongoid-paperclip
  mongoid-tree
  nifty-generators
  nokogiri
  omniauth!
  rails (= 3.1.0.rc5)
  rails-erd
  rails3-generators
  rake (= 0.8.7)
  rdoc
  redcarpet
  rspec (= 2.6.0)
  rspec-rails (= 2.6.1)
  ruby-debug19
  ruby-growl
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.0.rc)
  sax-machine
  simplecov (>= 0.4.0)
  spork (= 0.9.0.rc9)
  spork-testunit
  sprockets (~> 2.0.0.beta.12)
  test-unit
  therubyracer
  uglifier
  unicorn
  will_paginate
  yard
```

Comment: does your Gemfile.lock file point to the new version of nokogiri?

Comment: Please give us your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock - otherwise we'd be poking in the dark just like you are at the moment.

Comment: I added the files and, yes, the Gemfile.lock points to the new version of nokogiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that the gem source code on github does not include a .gemspec file, in my case I could not even get it to install

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'nokogiri',  :git => 'git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git'
```

run: bundle install, fails with

```
Could not find gem 'nokogiri (>= 0, runtime)' in git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'nokogiri (>= 0, runtime)'
```

did a google search and found this - https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/274

but since this is not from tenderlove git repo, I don't think that will work

looking at bundler homepage

```
If there is no .gemspec at the root of a git repository, you must specify a version that bundler should use when resolving dependencies
```

using this in the gem file I was at least able to install it, note the "1.5" addition

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'nokogiri', "1.5", :git => 'git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git'
```

I can't claim this will fix your issue, but I think your app is using the 'official' 1.5 release that still has issue, I don't think you were executing the code from ender672 git repo? they are both labeled as 1.5

contents of Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
    remote: git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git
    revision: 953e9b3b1ecf240c83c544f185461c7b86d387d5
    specs:
        nokogiri (1.5)

GEM
    remote: http://rubygems.org/
    specs:

PLATFORMS
    ruby

DEPENDENCIES
    nokogiri (= 1.5)!
```

I did not see remote: git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git in your Gemfile.lock, so assuming it is not really installed

hope this helps